# Cite Last Author with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

Is it possible to cite the last authors name from a bibliographic entry in a `\citeauthor{<key>}` fashion? Possibly even with an altered `andothers` string?

---

As an example from `biblatex-examples.bib`:

Input:

`\citeauthorlast{yoon}`, `\citeauthor{yoon}[last]` or similar?

Output:

`Ahn and coworkers` (instead of `Yoon et al.` from standard `\citeauthor{yoon}`)

---

I'm using `Biblatex` option `style=chem-angew`, hence the `et al.` in `\citeauthor{yoon}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citelastauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[labelname][\value{labelname}-\value{labelname}]{labelname}%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{1}
     {\setunit{\addspace}%
      \printtext{and colleague\ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{2}{s}{}}}
     {}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\citelastauthor{yoon,sigfridsson,worman}

\citelastauthor{herrmann}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This always gives you the last name in the name list and prints 'and colleague(s)' depending on the number of names.

[image: Ahn and colleagues, Ryde and colleague, Worman, Hoffmann and colleagues]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the fast help! I wonder why something like this is not implemented by default. Or is it just uncommon to cite like this?

Comment: @lcnittl This is highly field dependent I'd have thought. In some fields the order doesn't mean anything, in some fields the first author is most important, in some it's the last author ... When the name is used to generate a citation label that is always done by taking the order on the publication. But you are probably referring to the main researcher and his colleagues in a way not related to giving a citation label. `biblatex` does not provide commands for everything you could think of, but sometimes it is easy to implement regardless.